# Finding distance between polygons in same layer

Tags: qgis, distance, clustering

I would like to know the distance between polygons in a layer.

The goal is to know which houses are within 5 meters from each other in order to cluster them.

I tried adding a buffer and playing around it but I didn't manage to get what I want.

[image]

Comment: Try `v.cluster` with `dbscan`.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!! it works

Comment: Glad it helped! I don't have the time myself, so maybe add your exact solution as an answer to this question, and accept (yes, you can do that) to successfully resolve this post.

Comment: finally i used another solution, found somewhere in the internet, using the NNjoin plugin, but your proposition works as well, i will gladly post a solution in a few !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quiet straightforward :
Using the NNjoin plugin i made a self join of the house layer using the distance criterion
[image]

the result layer gives the distance between the houses!
[image]

a simple query gives all the houses within a 5 meter distance
"distance" <= 5

An alternative solution can be to use the v.cluster from the grass toolbox !